# Sharing of Connections in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

As per the documentation:

> "By default, each connection in SQL Developer is shared when possible.
>   For example, if you open a table in the Connections navigator and two
>   SQL Worksheets using the same connection, all three panes use one
>   shared connection to the database. In this example, a commit operation
>   in one SQL Worksheet commits across all three panes. If you want a
>   dedicated session, you must duplicate your connection and give it
>   another name. Sessions are shared by name, not connection information,
>   so this new connection will be kept separate from the original."

I opened connection1 and connection2 in the SQL developer for the same DB, and deleted all the rows from tableA in the connection1 ( no commit and rollback is performed) but when I checked in connecton2, all the rows are well present in the tableA.

If SQL developer is using shared connection then why all the rows from tableA are not deleted in the connection2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connections defined on the tree aren't shared. I can have two connections defined on the tree using same connection details but different names... SQLDev doesn't know they're the 'same' - they're not shared in any way.

But when you open one, that connection is shared between the worksheet, object browser , and reports.

And if you open 3 worksheets, they all share the one connection.

Unless you open an [unshared](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/10/unshared-worksheets-in-oracle-sql-developer-4/) worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeff. In my case, I have opened both connections from same connection. for example, connection name is Local_HR , connection1 and connection2 was opened from Local_HR only. I still don't get it why it is not a shared connection? and I have checked the preferences also, new worksheet to use unshared connection is unchecked.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by Connection1 and Connection2.

Comment: Hello Jeff, I did performed the test again and I am getting the desired result. Thanks for your help.